# Возникает ошибка при выборке из бд в resultSet.next()

Tags: java, android, mysql

```
connection = new DBConnection(ParamDB.host,ParamDB.name,ParamDB.password,ParamDB.nameDB);
        connection.iniProperties();
        connection.init();

        ResultSet resultSet = connection.query("SELECT password,name,location,education,fl,social_activ,experience,hobby,about,age FROM student where email ="+"'"+MainActivity.User+"'");
        try {
            while (resultSet.next()) { //вот здесь ошибка
                dataDB.add(resultSet.getString("password"));
                dataDB.add(resultSet.getString("name"));
                dataDB.add(resultSet.getString("location"));
                dataDB.add(resultSet.getString("education"));
                dataDB.add(resultSet.getString("fl"));
                dataDB.add(resultSet.getString("social_activ"));
                dataDB.add(resultSet.getString("experience"));
                dataDB.add(resultSet.getString("hobby"));
                dataDB.add(resultSet.getString("about"));
                dataDB.add(resultSet.getString("age"));

            }
        } catch (SQLException e4) {
            e4.printStackTrace();
        }
```

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>           Process: com.example.mydb, PID: 18210
>           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mydb/com.example.mydb.EditProfile}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean java.sql.ResultSet.next()' on a null object reference
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2747)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2808)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1541)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:165)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6375)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:883)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
>            Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean java.sql.ResultSet.next()' on a null object reference
>               at com.example.mydb.EditProfile.onCreate(EditProfile.java:46)
>               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6845)
>               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2700)

Как это решить помогите пожалуйста?

---

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_profile);
        final Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.reg);
        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
        name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
        password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
        age = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.age);
        experience = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.experience);
        social_activ = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.social_activ);
        about = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.about);
        location = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.location);
        education = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.education);
        hobby = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.hobby);
        language = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.language);



        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                connection = new DBConnection(ParamDB.host,ParamDB.name,ParamDB.password,ParamDB.nameDB);
                connection.iniProperties();
                connection.init();
                try {
                    ResultSet resultSet = connection.query("SELECT password,name,location,education,fl,social_activ,experience,hobby,about,age FROM student where email ="+"'"+MainActivity.User+"'");

                    while (resultSet.next()) {
                        dataDB.add(resultSet.getString("password"));
                        dataDB.add(resultSet.getString("name"));
                        dataDB.add(resultSet.getString("location"));
                        dataDB.add(resultSet.getString("education"));
                        dataDB.add(resultSet.getString("fl"));
                        dataDB.add(resultSet.getString("social_activ"));
                        dataDB.add(resultSet.getString("experience"));
                        dataDB.add(resultSet.getString("hobby"));
                        dataDB.add(resultSet.getString("about"));
                        dataDB.add(resultSet.getString("age"));

                    }
                } catch (SQLException e4) {
                    e4.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();

        System.out.println("DataDb "+dataDB.get(1));  //Ошибка


        switch (dataDB.get(4)) {
            case "English":
                pos_lang = 0;
                break;
            case "Spanish":
                pos_lang = 1;
                break;
            case "Poland":
                pos_lang = 2;
                break;
            case "Germany":
                pos_lang =3;
                break;
        }

        System.out.println("Data elem "+dataDB);
        password.setText(dataDB.get(0));
        name.setText(dataDB.get(1));
        location.setText(dataDB.get(2));
        education.setText(dataDB.get(3));
        language.setSelection(pos_lang);
        social_activ.setText(dataDB.get(5));
        experience.setText(dataDB.get(6));
        hobby.setText(dataDB.get(7));
        about.setText(dataDB.get(8));
        age.setText(dataDB.get(9));

    }
```

Вот так я сделал но почему-то список пуст и возникает ошибка

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.mydb, PID: 26815
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mydb/com.example.mydb.EditProfile}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2747)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2808)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1541)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:165)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6375)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:883)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
     Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
        at com.example.mydb.EditProfile.onCreate(EditProfile.java:77)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6845)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2700)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2808) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1541) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:165) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6375) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:883) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка понятна `resultSet == null` в момент обращения. Попробуйте так:

```
Connection con = ...;
    try {
        ResultSet rs = con.createStatement().executeQuery("Select...");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Замените свою строку

```
ResultSet resultSet = connection.query("SELECT password,name,location,education,fl,social_activ,experience,hobby,about,age FROM student where email ="+"'"+MainActivity.User+"'");
```

на

```
ResultSet resultSet = connection.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT password,name,location,education,fl,social_activ,experience,hobby,about,age FROM student where email ="+"'"+MainActivity.User+"'");
```